# In views, add class depending on the user input in a checkbox.

Tags: 7, views

I need to add a class to a field of views depending if the user wants to have an overlay on the image or no. We need to use a checkbox for the user to input if it needs the class or no.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create your boolean field (my case the name is field_no_overlay),  The checkbox should have the values for the classes you want to use and apply to your field.

[image: Checkbox Overlay Field Setting]

2. In the views, rewrite your value [image: rewrite the results].
3. Create the style for each class.